# Magento 2 : how to add color swatches on list page

Tags: magento2, product-list, color-swatches

Is it possible to add color swatches on the list page and color dropdown on the product view(detail) page?.

Please check below image, I added color attribute as a dropdown:
[image]

So by default on the product view page showing dropdown of the color attribute.

Now I need to add color swatches on product list page.

Is it possible?. If it's possible let me know how to set color swatches on the product list page.

Thank you so much.

Comment: check this link --- https://bsscommerce.com/blog/2-easy-steps-to-add-color-swatch-in-magento-2/

Comment: @MohitPatel Thanks for reply. The default view page dropdown is perfect but I need color swatches only on list page.

Comment: You want to different page different styles show???.view page drop down and listing page color swatches ???

Comment: @MohitPatel yeah right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution.

step-1: open admin > stores > attribute > product > search color and change color attribute from the dropdown to swatch.

step-2: open vendor/magento/module-swatches/Block/Product/Renderer/Configurable.php file

Replace line

```
const SWATCH_RENDERER_TEMPLATE = 'Magento_Swatches::product/view/renderer.phtml';
```

To line

```
const SWATCH_RENDERER_TEMPLATE = 'Magento_ConfigurableProduct::product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml';
```

Now, flush cache and check. You can see swatches on the Product list(category) page and dropdown on product view(detail) page.

Comment: I want to add color in listing page and images on product view page. Any idea regarding it?